# Put a colored circle or symbol before theorem title

Tags: formatting, symbols, color, theorems

I am used to coloring Theorems, definitions, and examples differently in my handwritten notes. This would be messy to print, but It would be nice if I could add a small colored symbol just before the keywords.

For example, say I have a rendered pdf with:

```
Theorem 6.3
Definition 6.14
```

how could I get:

```
{red circle}Theorem 6.3
{blue circle}Definition 6.14
```

I know I could probably color the whole environments differently but I am looking for a very minimal distinction.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\textcolor{red}{\textbullet} Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet} Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wonderful, so easy! did not think about it